THE MULTI-PART IDENTIFIER COULD NOT BE BOUND
USE [GRPAN]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



--exec dbo.DYN_RPT_BALANCEDEPRUEBAPORRANGODEFECHAS2 '20190201','20190307',1,'2335','2345'
-- Este no genera cuentas sin saldo ni movimiento
create procedure [dbo].[DYN_RPT_BALANCEDEPRUEBAPORRANGODEFECHAS2] @FINICIAL datetime
    , @FFINAL datetime
    , @LIBRO varchar(100)
    , @COUNT1 varchar(50)
    , @COUNT2 varchar(50)
as
/*
Descripcion: Genera un reporte de balance financiero por rango de fechas tomando como base las tablas de acumulado de 
periodo de GP (GL1x110) mas los movimientos financieros (GLx0000).

Procedimiento:
Para la porción de saldo inicial que se toma de los acumulados se necesita conocer:
    cual es el periodo inmediatamente anterior al inicio del rango de fechas, y,
    cuando fue el último año cerrado para solo tomar un periodo 0

Del movimiento se toma desde la fecha final del último periodo acumulado hasta la fecha final del rango y dependiendo 
de la fecha del movimiento se clasifica como saldo inicial o como debitos o créditos del periodo
*/
begin
    set nocount on;

    exec dbo.DYN_SRPT_ARBOLPUC_NSAPUC

    declare @UltAnoCerrado smallint = 0
        , @PeriodoInicial int
        , @AnoInicial int
        , @AnoUltimoBBF int = 0

    set @UltAnoCerrado = (
            select max(YEAR1)
            from SY40101 with (nolock)
            where HISTORYR = 1
            )

    select top 1 @PeriodoInicial = PERIODID
        , @AnoInicial = YEAR1
    from SY40100 with (nolock)
    where SERIES = 0
        and PERDENDT < @FINICIAL
    order by PERIODDT desc

    select top 1 @AnoUltimoBBF = HSTYEAR
    from GL30000 with (nolock)
    where PERIODID = 0
        and HSTYEAR <= @AnoInicial
    order by HSTYEAR desc

    select IND = GL.ACTINDX
        , DESCRIPCION = max(ACTDESCR)
        , DEBITO = sum(DB)
        , CREDITO = sum(CR)
        , SALDOINI = sum(SI)
        , CTA = max(B.ACTNUMBR_1)
        , ACTNUMST = max(ACTNUMST)
        , ACTDESCR = max(ACTDESCR)
        , ACTNUMBR_1 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_1)
        , ACTNUMBR_2 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_2)
        , ACTNUMBR_3 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_3)
        , ACTNUMBR_4 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_4)
        , ACTNUMBR_5 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_5)
        , ACTNUMBR_6 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_6)
        , ACTNUMBR_7 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_7)
        , ACTNUMBR_8 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_8)
        , ACTNUMBR_9 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_9)
        , ACTNUMBR_10 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_10)
        , PUCCODE = max(B.PUCCODE)
        , max(PUC1.nsa_Descripcion_Codigo) as DESC_ACTNUMBR_1
        , max(PUC2.nsa_Descripcion_Codigo) as DESC_ACTNUMBR_2
        , max(PUC3.nsa_Descripcion_Codigo) as DESC_ACTNUMBR_3
        , max(PUC4.nsa_Descripcion_Codigo) as DESC_ACTNUMBR_4
        , max(PUC5.nsa_Descripcion_Codigo) as DESC_ACTNUMBR_5
        , max(PUC6.nsa_Descripcion_Codigo) as DESC_ACTNUMBR_6
        , max(PUC7.nsa_Descripcion_Codigo) as DESC_ACTNUMBR_7
        , max(PUC8.nsa_Descripcion_Codigo) as DESC_ACTNUMBR_8
        , max(PUC9.nsa_Descripcion_Codigo) as DESC_ACTNUMBR_9
        , max(PUC10.nsa_Descripcion_Codigo) as DESC_ACTNUMBR_10
    from (
        -- Tome saldo de periodo inicial de años abiertos o cerrados
        select GL10110.ACTINDX
            , sum(PERDBLNC) SI
            , convert(numeric(19, 5), 0) DB
            , convert(numeric(19, 5), 0) CR
            , 'SIPO' origen
        from GL10110 with(nolock)
        inner join GL00105 with(nolock)
            on GL00105.ACTINDX = GL10110.ACTINDX
                and GL00105.ACTNUMST between @COUNT1 and @COUNT2
        where Ledger_ID in ( select Param from DYN_FUN_SEPARADORCOMAS(@LIBRO, ',') )
            and @AnoInicial > @UltAnoCerrado
            and ( YEAR1 < @AnoInicial
                or ( YEAR1 = @AnoInicial and PERIODID <= @PeriodoInicial)
                )
        group by GL10110.ACTINDX
        
        union all
        
        select GL10111.ACTINDX
            , sum(PERDBLNC) SI
            , convert(numeric(19, 5), 0) DB
            , convert(numeric(19, 5), 0) CR
            , 'SIPH' origen
        from GL10111 with (nolock)
        inner join GL00105 with(nolock)
            on GL00105.ACTINDX = GL10111.ACTINDX
                and GL00105.ACTNUMST between @COUNT1 and @COUNT2
        where Ledger_ID in ( select Param from DYN_FUN_SEPARADORCOMAS(@LIBRO, ',') )
            and @AnoInicial <= @UltAnoCerrado
            and YEAR1 >= @AnoUltimoBBF
            and ( YEAR1 < @AnoInicial
                or ( YEAR1 = @AnoInicial and PERIODID <= @PeriodoInicial)
                )
        group by GL10111.ACTINDX
        
        union all
        
        -- Tome movimientos
        select GL30000.ACTINDX
            , sum(case when TRXDATE < @FINICIAL then DEBITAMT - CRDTAMNT else 0 end) SI
            , sum(case when TRXDATE >= @FINICIAL then DEBITAMT else 0 end) DB
            , sum(case when TRXDATE >= @FINICIAL then CRDTAMNT else 0 end) CR
            , 'SIMH' origen
        from GL30000 with (nolock)
        inner join GL00105 with(nolock)
            on GL00105.ACTINDX = GL30000.ACTINDX
                and GL00105.ACTNUMST between @COUNT1 and @COUNT2
        where Ledger_ID in ( select Param from DYN_FUN_SEPARADORCOMAS(@LIBRO, ',') )
            and TRXDATE <= @FFINAL
            and PERIODID <> 0
            and ( HSTYEAR > @AnoInicial
                or ( HSTYEAR = @AnoInicial and PERIODID > @PeriodoInicial)
                )
        group by GL30000.ACTINDX
        
        union all
        
        select GL20000.ACTINDX
            , sum(case when TRXDATE < @FINICIAL then DEBITAMT - CRDTAMNT else 0 end) SI
            , sum(case when TRXDATE >= @FINICIAL then DEBITAMT else 0 end) DB
            , sum(case when TRXDATE >= @FINICIAL then CRDTAMNT else 0 end) CR
            , 'SIMO' origen
        from GL20000 with (nolock)
        inner join GL00105 with(nolock)
            on GL00105.ACTINDX = GL20000.ACTINDX
                and GL00105.ACTNUMST between @COUNT1 and @COUNT2
        where Ledger_ID in ( select Param from DYN_FUN_SEPARADORCOMAS(@LIBRO, ',') )
            and TRXDATE <= @FFINAL
            and PERIODID <> 0
            and ( OPENYEAR > @AnoInicial
                or ( OPENYEAR = @AnoInicial and PERIODID > @PeriodoInicial)
                )
        group by GL20000.ACTINDX
        ) GL
    inner join GL00100
        on GL00100.ACTINDX = GL.ACTINDX
    inner join GL00105
        on GL00105.ACTINDX = GL.ACTINDX
    left join nsaPUC_GL00100
        on nsaPUC_GL00100.ACTINDX = GL.ACTINDX
    left join ##DYN_TABLE_ARBOLPUC B
        on nsaPUC_GL00100.PUCCODE = B.PUCCODE
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC1
        on B.ACTNUMBR_1 = REPLACE(PUC1.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC2
        on B.ACTNUMBR_2 = REPLACE(PUC2.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC3
        on B.ACTNUMBR_3 = REPLACE(PUC3.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC4
        on B.ACTNUMBR_4 = REPLACE(PUC4.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC5
        on B.ACTNUMBR_5 = REPLACE(PUC5.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC6
        on B.ACTNUMBR_6 = REPLACE(PUC6.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC7
        on B.ACTNUMBR_7 = REPLACE(PUC7.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC8
        on B.ACTNUMBR_8 = REPLACE(PUC8.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC9
        on B.ACTNUMBR_9 = REPLACE(PUC9.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC10
        on B.ACTNUMBR_10 = REPLACE(PUC10.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
    group by GL.ACTINDX
    having sum(DB) <> 0
        or sum(CR) <> 0
        or sum(SI) <> 0
    order by ACTNUMST
end
GO

Me muestra ERROR EN B.ACNUMBR_1, B.ACNUMBR_2, B.ACNUMBR_3, B.ACNUMBR_4, B.ACNUMBR_5, B.ACNUMBR_6, B.ACNUMBR_7, B.ACNUMBR_8, B.ACNUMBR_9, B.ACNUMBR_10, B.PUCCODE
ME DICE QUE

THE MULTI-PART IDENTIFIER B.ACNUMBR_1, B.ACNUMBR_2, B.ACNUMBR_3, B.ACNUMBR_4, B.ACNUMBR_5, B.ACNUMBR_6, B.ACNUMBR_7, B.ACNUMBR_8, B.ACNUMBR_9, B.ACNUMBR_10, B.PUCCODE  COULD NOT BE BOUND.


El mensaje de error que mencionas no puede aparecer tal cual, pues tu script en ningún lugar hace referencia a un identificador B.ACNUMBR_1.
A lo que hace referencia tu script es a B.ACTNUMBR_1, por lo que aislando este campo únicamente, el mensaje de error sería algo como:
THE MULTI-PART IDENTIFIER B.ACTNUMBR_1 COULD NOT BE BOUND.

Mi traducción libre para este mensaje sería:
EL IDENTIFICADOR DE VARIAS PARTES B.ACTNUMBR_1 NO SE PUDO VINCULAR.

Vemos que el identificador aparece en estas expresiones:
    select
-- ..
        , CTA = max(B.ACTNUMBR_1)
-- ..
        , ACTNUMBR_1 = max(B.ACTNUMBR_1)
-- ..
    from 
-- ..
    left join nsaPUC_GL10000 PUC1
        on B.ACTNUMBR_1 = REPLACE(PUC1.nsa_Codigo, '-', '')
-- ..

La interpretación del mensaje es que no logra encontrar, entre el texto de la consulta y la estructura de la base de datos, a qué vincular el identificador B.ACTNUMBR_1. Lo llama identificador multipartes, ya que contiene puntos que son los separadores de estas partes.
Dado que el identificador tiene dos partes, hay dos posibles causas para ese error, la primera es que no haya una tabla o conjunto de datos en la consulta que se pueda relacionar con el alias B. Revisando vemos que no es el caso, pues en la cláusula from encontramos:
    left join ##DYN_TABLE_ARBOLPUC B

Por lo que la primera parte si tiene correspondencia a la tabla temporal ##DYN_TABLE_ARBOLPUC.
La segunda posible causa es que dicho conjunto de datos, en este caso la tabla temporal ##DYN_TABLE_ARBOLPUC no tenga un campo llamado ACTNUMBR_1.
Dado que no hay más partes, este debe ser el caso. Como no tenemos visibilidad de la creación de dicha tabla, queda al AP como ejercicio confirmarlo, pero realmente no hay otra posible causa.

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, es correcto lo que dices el error sale EL IDENTIFICADOR DE VARIAS PARTES B.ACTNUMBR_1 NO SE PUDO VINCULAR. si ni que puse todos los campos porque en B.ACTNUMBR_2, B.ACTNUMBR_3 ....... me sale lo mismo entonces por eso puse lo mismo.
Y tengo una pregunta no hay posibilidad de ver esa tabla temporal para ver que campos tiene ?

Pues, quien tiene acceso a la estructura sos vos. Podés ver que campos tiene inspeccionando el código que la crea, o ejecutándolo y haciendo un select sobre ella.

La verdad no  pude lograr solucionar el problema. :(

Aunque creo que la pregunta original está respondida, siempre puedes considerar editarla e incluir la estructura de la tabla temporal o el código que la genera en la pregunta (siempre en forma de [mcve], por ejemplo con los campos llave esenciales y un campo de los problemáticos) para tener más ojos sobre el origen problema.
